# How to get values selected in Treelist Queryable field

Tags: powershell-extensions, tree-list

We have try to find all items under treelist field.

**Example**

```
$rawIds = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField]$page.Fields["Sub Category Pages"]
```

Here getting `$rawIds` as `null`.

Please note here "Sub Category Pages" is **TreeList Queryable** field. If any field type is `mutlilist` then we are getting data.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `TreeList Queryable` is not a built-in Sitecore field type.

Maybe there is something missing while mapping custom field types to `MultilistField`.

You can map value on your own using:

```
$rawIds = [Sitecore.Data.ID]::ParseArray($page["Sub Category Pages"])
```

Comment: Thanks Marek. Still am getting null with suggested code. This is custom field which inherit Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.TreeList.

Comment: Are you  sure you don't have any typo in field name? And that you're checking right language version/right database, etc? What is the output of `$page["Sub Category Pages"]`?